# Mixpanel Data to Google Sheets

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mixpanel

I am trying to push mixpanel data into a single Google Sheet using code from here:
https://github.com/melissaguyre/mixpanel-segmentation-google-spreadsheets

I am having issues with the `API_PARAMETERS` not looping through as expected. (Formula, Formula1, & Formula2) The first two parameters loop through fine, but when the final is added, I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "2016-07-11" from undefined. (line 143, file "Code")

Here is the code:

```
* Step 1) Fill in your account's Mixpanel Information here
 `enter code here`*/
var API_KEY = '******';
var API_SECRET = '****';

/**
 * Step 2) Define the tab # at which to create new sheets in the spreadsheet.
 * 0 creates a new sheet as the first sheet. 
 * 1 creates a new sheet at the second sheet and so forth.
 */
var CREATE_NEW_SHEETS_AT = 0;

/**
 * Step 3) Define date range as a string in format of 'yyyy-mm-dd' or '2013-09-13'
 *
 * Today's Date: set equal to getMixpanelDateToday() 
 * Yesterday's Date: set equal to getMixpanelDateYesterday() 
 */
var FROM_DATE = getMixpanelDate(7);
var TO_DATE = getMixpanelDate(1);

/**
 * Step 4) Define Segmentation Queries - Get data for an event, segmented and filtered by properties.

var API_PARAMETERS = {
   'Formula' : [ 'QuestionAsked', '(properties["InputMethod"]) == "Voice" or (properties["InputMethod"]) == "Text" ', 'general', 'day', 'B7'],
   'Formula1' : [ 'QuestionAsked', '(properties["InputMethod"]) == "Voice" or (properties["InputMethod"]) == "Text" ', 'unique', 'day', 'B2'],
   //'Formula2' :  [ 'QuestionAnswered', '(properties["InputMethod"]) == "Voice" or (properties["InputMethod"]) == "Text" ', 'unique', 'day', 'B3' ],
};





// Iterates through the hash map of queries, gets the data, writes it to spreadsheet
function getMixpanelData() {
  for (var i in API_PARAMETERS)
  {
    var cell = API_PARAMETERS[i][4];
    fetchMixpanelData(i, cell);

  }
}

// Creates a menu in spreadsheet for easy user access to above function
function onOpen() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  activeSpreadsheet.addMenu(
      "Mixpanel", [{
        name: "Get Mixpanel Data", functionName: "getMixpanelData"
      }]);
}

/**
 * Gets data from mixpanel api and inserts to spreadsheet
 *
 */
function fetchMixpanelData(sheetName, cell) {

  var c = cell;

  var expires = getApiExpirationTime();
  var urlParams = getApiParameters(expires, sheetName).join('&')
       + "&sig=" + getApiSignature(expires, sheetName);

  // Add URL Encoding for special characters which might generate 'Invalid argument' errors. 
  // Modulus should always be encoded first due to the % sign.
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\%/g, '%25');   
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\s/g, '%20');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\[/g, '%5B');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\]/g, '%5D');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\"/g, '%22');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\(/g, '%28');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\)/g, '%29');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\>/g, '%3E');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\</g, '%3C');
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\-/g, '%2D');   
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\+/g, '%2B');   
  urlParams = urlParams.replace(/\//g, '%2F');

  var url = "http://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/segmentation?" + urlParams;
  Logger.log("THE URL  " + url);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var json = response.getContentText();
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(json);

  var dates = dataAll.data.series;
  Logger.log(API_PARAMETERS);
  for (i in API_PARAMETERS){
    var parametersEntry = API_PARAMETERS[i]; 
    for (i in dates){
      data = dataAll.data.values[parametersEntry[0]][dates[i]]; 
    }
    insertSheet(data, c);
  };
}


function insertSheet(value, cell) {

  var sheetName = 'Formula';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  var c = sheet.getRange(cell).setValue(value);


};



/** 
 * Returns an array of query parameters
 */
function getApiParameters(expires, sheetName) {
  var parametersEntry = API_PARAMETERS[sheetName];
  return [
        'api_key=' + API_KEY,
        'expire=' + expires,
        'event=' + parametersEntry[0],
        'where=' + parametersEntry[1],
        'type=' + parametersEntry[2],
        'unit=' + parametersEntry[3],
        'from_date=' + FROM_DATE,
        'to_date=' + TO_DATE
    ];
}

/** 
 * Sorts provided array of parameters
 *

function sortApiParameters(parameters) { 
  var sortedParameters = parameters.sort();
  // Logger.log("sortApiParameters() " + sortedParameters);

  return sortedParameters;
}

/** 

function getApiExpirationTime() {
  var expiration = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;
  // Logger.log("getApiExpirationTime() " + expiration);

  return expiration;
}

/** 
 * Returns API Signature calculated using api_secret. 
 */
function getApiSignature(expires, sheetName) {
  var parameters = getApiParameters(expires, sheetName);
  var sortedParameters = sortApiParameters(parameters).join('') + API_SECRET;
  // Logger.log("Sorted Parameters  " + sortedParameters);

  var digest = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, sortedParameters);

  var signature = '';
  for (j = 0; j < digest.length; j++) {
      var hashVal = digest[j];
      if (hashVal < 0) hashVal += 256; 
      if (hashVal.toString(16).length == 1) signature += "0";
      signature += hashVal.toString(16);
  }

  return signature;
}



/** 
 *********************************************************************************
 * Date helpers
 *********************************************************************************
 */

// Returns today's date string in Mixpanel date format '2013-09-11'
function getMixpanelDateToday() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; 
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  } 
  if ( mm < 10 ) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  } 

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  return today;
}

// Returns yesterday's's date string in Mixpanel date format '2013-09-11'
function getMixpanelDate(days){
  var today = new Date();
  var d = new Date(today);
  d.setDate(today.getDate() - days);

  //Logger.log(yesterday);
  var dd = d.getDate();
  //Logger.log(yesterday);
  var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = d.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }

  d = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  //Logger.log(yesterday);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: You should supply only the minimum code required to reproduce your issue, rather than your entire working script. It also appears that you commented out swathes of this code - is that intentional? Perhaps that is the source of your issue?